# Geo Api in TPL file

Tags: javascript, prestashop, smarty

I am using this code to display a div only for clients from United Kingdom and it works through built-in page builder - prestashop.

Unfortunately I cannot make it work in tpl file for address form.
Basically I need a text below the address form.

```
    <div class="hide GB">text</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    {literal}
    $.get("https://freegeoip.app/json/", function (response) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(response.country_code)[0].style.display = "block";
    }, "jsonp");
    {/literal}
    </script>
```

I also tried this one:

```
{literal}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$.ajax("https://freegeoip.app/json/")
  .done(function (e) {
  $('.hide').eq(e.country_code === 'GB' ? 0 : 1).show();
});</script>
<div class="hide">text</div>
<div id="country_code"></div>
{/literal}
```

They both work in the fiddle. They both work in the page builder when added as raw html (without literal tags ofc)

However I cannot make them to work in adrress-form.tpl file for some reason. The text just wont show. However the country code is being displayed where I want it. It is just the text that wont.
Any ideas?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
{literal}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<div id="GB">text</div>
<script>$.get("https://freegeoip.app/json/", function (response) {
    $("#country_code").html(response.country_code);
    if(response.country_code=='GB'){
        document.getElementById(response.country_code).style.display = "block";
    }
}, "jsonp");</script>


{/literal}
```

I actually solved this with this code.
CSS wise:

```
#GB{display:none;}
```